# Customize the login in politic FOS UserBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hi everyone i'm on a symfony2 and mongodb project..i've installed recently Fos UserBundle and i need to customize the politic of logging in : in fact i want that the user introduce only a pin code to connect to my web application..i found how to log in with email instead of username but changing the whole logic of the authentication i didn't find anything about it. any one can help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You must write your own user provider.

After you create your user provider and declare it as service, use it's id in security.yml under:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: your_bundle.user_provider
```

The following two tutorials will help you. (no code added here as it's too much)
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: i fallowed all the tutorial but it seems that it have any effect on my application: i introduce the url of my application and it enter directly with no authentication

Comment: Please post your security.yml file, and the custom provider. Put them in your original question.